# What Bluetooth 4.0 devices and radios are available?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Bluetooth 4.0 is the latest specification to be adopted by the Bluetooth cabal, which notably adds Bluetooth low energy into the mix, which is designed to allow radios that sip battery like 802.15.4 ("ZigBee") to directly connect to consumer devices.

It sounds great, and according to a search for "bluetooth 4.0 devices", we are swimming in them because they all showed up Q4 2010, however I can barely find more than a single chip (TI CC2540), let alone *any* consumer product that is BT 4.0.  Where are they?

Comment: The iPhone 4s is 4.0.

Answer (score 7):

## Consumer Devices

### Android

- Samsung phones<sup>*[specify]*</sup>
- HTC phones<sup>*[specify]*</sup>

Android 4.3 (API level 18) comes with an official [Bluetooth Low Energy API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).  In older versions, BLE was not integrated into the Android API so each manufacturer had/has their own API.

### Apple

#### iOS

- iPhone 4S, 5+
- iPad 3g, 4g, mini
- iPod Touch 5g, Nano 7g

#### OS X

- MacBook Air (Mid 2011/Model 4,x+)
- Mac Mini (Mid 2011/Model 5,x+)

---

## Modules

### BlueGiga

- [BLE112](http://www.bluegiga.com/BLE112_Bluetooth_Smart_module) - single mode, programmable micro (8051) with spare GPIO/ADC
- [BLE113](http://www.bluegiga.com/BLE113_Bluetooth_Smart_module) - like 112 but with USB interface and additional BlueGiga stack software(?)
- [BT111](http://www.bluegiga.com/bt111) - dual mode (LE/classic), programmable micro

### RedBear

- [BLE Shield/BLE Mini](http://redbearlab.com/) - hobbyist-level modules, may lack FCC cert.

### Laird Technologies

- [BL600 Series](http://www.lairdtech.com/products/bl600-series)
- [BL620 Series](http://www.lairdtech.com/products/bl620)

### muRata Technologies

- There are three modules: [Type VZ, Type WS, Type 1BX](http://wireless.murata.com/eng/products/rf-modules-1/bluetooth/where/rfm-bluetooth/v4.0-ble.html)

### connectBlue

- [OLP425](http://www.connectblue.com/technologies/bluetooth-low-energy-technology/)

### Roving Networks, acquired by Microchip

- [RN4020](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=RN4020)
- [RN4677](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=RN4677)

---

## ICs

### TI

- [CC2541](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2541) BLE SoC
- [CC2560](http://www.ti.com/product/cc2560) Bluetooth 4.0 dual mode supported
- lots.

### Nordic Semi

- [nRF51822](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/nRF51822)
- nRF80001
- nRF80002

Comment: CC254x and Nordic ones are NOT Bluetooth 4.0 but Bluetooth LE only. I think this post may confuse people to think that they can do 4.0 with this.

Comment: @TõnuSamuel the post is CW, feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3):

CSR8000

http://www.csr.com/products/54/csr8000-platform

Answer (score 2):

- TI cc2540, get the mini dev kit http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2540dk-mini
- Nordic Semiconductor nRF8001, get the dev kit http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-R-low-energy/nRF8001-Development-Kit

  - BlueGiga BLED112

Comment: +1 to nRF8001 that has plenty of stuff integrated, making it easier. They also have iPhone demo app so it's ready to go. Relatively easy to integrate.

Comment: This is NOT Bluetooth 4.0 but Bluetooth LE.

Answer (score 0):

We've used the CC256x from TI which is a dual mode radio. Capable of Bluetooth and BLE. You need an external microcontroller but idesign isn't difficult.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the Dialog DA14580 quite a lot. There is a development kit available with a lot of source code and documentation. It's an integrated ARM Cortex-M0 with an integrated BLE radio running the rivierawaves BLE software stack.

It may be worth to look it up.